# How to build a password protected, web-based, proxy server?

Tags: browser, proxy, webserver

Yesterday, I took advantage of a deal offered by a web hosting company, FatCow, to buy a year's worth of "unlimited" hosting for $1. So now I want to take advantage of that by deploying a password protected proxy server that can be accessible from any browser. The proxy server must be able to allow me to log in to any site and visit any `https` page. From the browser to the proxy server, the connection must be encrypted. In other words, I should be seeing something along the lines of `https://www.myproxysite.com/https://www.unblockedwebsite.com`. I would prefer it if the proxy would scramble the web address so anyone peeking into my web history wouldn't be able just click on any of the links and see the full address of the website I went to. Any suggestions on how to start?

Comment: Is FatCow a VPS hosting company? What degree of freedom do you have in your account? root account? Can you install apache? Which OS?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I'm techish only in the sense that I know my way around a computer much better than the average person, but not enough to manage a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try a combination of **[Glype](http://www.glype.com/)** and `.htaccess` protection

Glype provided all features you needed, and it only require PHP5 and cURL (I believe all hostings support that)

`.htaccess` is very simple to setup. Here is [one](http://proxy.org/forum/glype-proxy-discussion/969-how-keep-proxy-sites-secret.html) instruction

Comment: Thanks, I have it set up. But it appears as if I can't submit comments on Reddit. I can log in fine, though. In addition, Glype doesn't seem to support https encryption.

Comment: Scratch that, FatCow already allows me to do this by simply attaching 'https' to the front part of the address.